# Menu inflater not running on emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, menu, android-emulator, android-manifest

I am trying to use the menu inflator to give the user the option to email me for support, but everytime I hit the menu button on the emulator it will do nothing.

Would I need to edit this in my manifest? My xml has menu as the title and items for the well items.

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/email" android:title="@string/email_menu"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_envelope" android:onClick="emailme" />
    <item android:id="@+id/test1" android:title="@string/test1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard" android:onClick="test1" />

</menu>
```

Activity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MenuButton extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.menu.menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.email:
                emailme();
                return true;
            case R.id.test1:
                test1();
                return false;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void test1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    private void emailme() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String domsEmail = "MYEMAIL@EXAMPLE.com";
        String message = "Hello, I just want to let you know that your app";
        String myemail[] = { domsEmail };
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, myemail);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "your app");
        emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        startActivity(emailIntent);
    }   
}
```

Comment: could you also post the xml code of your menu.xml..might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are various issues with your code:

1. Please have `onCreateOptionsMenu()` use `return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(...))` with the same parameters that you receive -- in other words, chain to the superclass when you are done
2. Your `android:onClick` attributes will only work on API Level 11 and higher, and your methods that you have tied to them need to be `public` and have a `MenuItem` parameter (which yours do not)
3. Your MIME type in `emailme()` needs to be `text/plain`, not `plain/text`

Comment: so does my code look correct now? `public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     ....
     return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));`

and `public void test1(MenuItem item) ` also in my switch i would add `test1(item);` correct?

idk if it is my code or emulator but I still couldn't get it to work, also could you explain or point out why I would need to return the super?

Comment: @Dominic: "so does my code look correct now?" -- your code is the same as it was when I answered the question. Here is a sample project showing the use of menus: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Menus/Inflation

Comment: Okay so before I get in over my head if I wanted to just make a menu inflator I can just do that with the `onCreateOptionsMenu` correct? I wouldn't need much other code to just get the menu when clicked to pull up a list of options? I think that is where I am stuck on

Comment: @Dominic: "if I wanted to just make a menu inflator I can just do that with the onCreateOptionsMenu correct?" -- yes.

Comment: okay, now If that is not my mainscreen but it is another class I would have to link them in the manifest, correct? I don't know how else it would call my mainmenu.java and I assume that is why my inflator is not being used. again I want to thank you for helping